# MongoDB can't run MacOS

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, server

```
Murats-Air:~ murat$ mongod
2020-05-26T14:28:14.858-0400 I  CONTROL  [main] Automatically disabling TLS 1.0, to force-enable TLS 1.0 specify --sslDisabledProtocols 'none'
2020-05-26T14:28:14.862-0400 W  ASIO     [main] No TransportLayer configured during NetworkInterface startup
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] MongoDB starting : pid=706 port=27017 dbpath=/data/db 64-bit host=Murats-Air.home
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] db version v4.2.7
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] git version: 51d9fe12b5d19720e72dcd7db0f2f17dd9a19212
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] allocator: system
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] modules: none
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] build environment:
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     distarch: x86_64
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten]     target_arch: x86_64
2020-05-26T14:28:14.863-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] options: {}
2020-05-26T14:28:14.864-0400 I  STORAGE  [initandlisten] exception in initAndListen: NonExistentPath: Data directory /data/db not found. Create the missing directory or specify another path using (1) the --dbpath command line option, or (2) by adding the 'storage.dbPath' option in the configuration file., terminating
2020-05-26T14:28:14.865-0400 I  NETWORK  [initandlisten] shutdown: going to close listening sockets...
2020-05-26T14:28:14.865-0400 I  -        [initandlisten] Stopping further Flow Control ticket acquisitions.
2020-05-26T14:28:14.865-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] now exiting
2020-05-26T14:28:14.865-0400 I  CONTROL  [initandlisten] shutting down with code:100
```

I cannot solve the problem. I had tried to kill all processes mongod there was no running processes on mongod.

I tried to create /data/db directory but I got an error that 'it is for read-only'. Can anybody tell what is the problem here.

Comment: You need a data directory; if you cannot create one at `/data/db` then use one of the two other options listed.

Comment: Please describe how you installed it. If you follow the [official installation guide](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-os-x/#install-mongodb-community-edition) from MongoDB, it suggests you install it using `homebrew`. The default data path would be `/usr/local/var/mongodb`

Answer (score 0):

You can try to go with a local data directory like

```
mkdir mongodata
mongod --dbpath=./mongodata
```

If that works, confirm that you set proper permissions on the `/data/db` folder.

Generally for dev environments I'd advise against running things in some global `/data/db` folder and go with local per-project ones, or creating a dedicated data folder in your user directory and setting it inside a configuration file. The last more advanced option is to run a mongodb docker container if you are comfortable with those.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem by using a manual run method:

```
mongod --dbpath /usr/local/var/mongodb --logpath/usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log --fork
```

every time I run with this code and then I use `mongo`